# Add Classpath Container to Eclipse Plugin’s Runtime

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, osgi-bundle, eclipse-pde

We use a classpath container (provided by [Buildship](http://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.buildship)) to manage non-plugin dependencies in our Eclipse Plugin Project:

[image]

This works very well and the projects compile as expected.

However, if we launch our project using an “Eclipse Application” run configuration, we get errors like

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/commons/collections4/multiset/HashMultiSet
```

as soon as our plugin is activated. So obviously, Eclipse uses the classpath container to *compile* the project, but does not add it *at runtime*.

I’ve searched the internet quite a while to find a solution for this, buy I didn’t:

**How do I tell Eclipse to add the classpath container to the project’s runtime classpath?**

I did not find any option to do this.
I know I could add the dependencies’ jars to the classpath in `MANIFEST.MF`, but I’m not willing to do so. This *completely* contradicts the idea of classpath containers. Instead, I want Eclipse to automatically add all jars from the classpath container to the runtime classpath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution that works for us:

#### Development

During development, we load the dependency jars by adding them to the bootclasspath. For “Eclipse Application” run configurations, we can add the following to the configuration’s JVM arguments:

```
 -Xbootclasspath/a:"${project_classpath:Project1}:${project_classpath:Project2}"
```

This is convenient, because it will add all classpath containsers to the runtime. So we can have true dependency management through gradle and classpath containers.

#### Production

For production, we’ll wrap our dependencies as Osgi bundles and automatically add them to `MANIFEST.MF`. We’re using gradle to build our project, so this shouldn’t be a problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this, everything the plug-in depends on must be listed in the MANIFEST.MF in the 'Require-Bundle', or 'Import-Package' or 'Bundle-Classpath'.

When you export a plugin there is no information about the project classpath included in the plugin.

Comment: I thought so. But I also thought that Eclipse would be able to let me configure a classpath container and adapt the MANIFEST.MF when building. But there is no such option, is there?

Comment: Sorry, no such option. In fact for a plugin you should do things the other way round - you set things in the MANIFEST.MF and Eclipse will update the project classpath to match (see the 'update the classpath settings' on the Overview tab of the manifest editor).

Comment: But this is only possible if Eclipse somehow knows the dependency as an Osgi bundle. But for dependencies that aren’t Eclipse plugins (and these are the ones I’m talking about, this does not work :(